# How does the Spring Framework protect against cross-site scripting?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cross-browser

Cross-Site scripting(XSS) is an attack that happens due to flaws in browsers.As XSS is a front-end problem spring does not follows any mechanism to protect against XSS ?

Comment: This is a more spring security thing. Check this link - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html

Answer (score 1):

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_SheetXSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet

Not Spring, but useful:

Anti cross-site scripting (XSS) filter for Java web apps
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/anti-cross-site-scripting-xss-filter.html

This should help a bit:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>

    <param-value>true</param-value>

</context-param>
<spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape="true" /> 
<form:input path="someFormField" htmlEscape="true" />
```

To avoid XSS security threat in spring application
https://jeevanpatil.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/prevention_of_xss/